# Is it possible to pass in PHP variables into a custom Listener for PHPUnit if the Listener is defined in phpunit.xml?

Tags: php, phpunit

## Situation

I may not be using PHPUnit in its traditional sense.  I'm using PHPUnit with Selenium 2.  We had this idea to record the actions Selenium is performing in a "steps to reproduce" sort of way.  Meaning if we call Selenium to "click" or "type", the action is recorded.  If an action fails, it is also recorded.  We aren't calling asserts to setup-type actions.  For example, if we're testing a page to view customer information, but before we can even get to that page we need to login, we don't assert the login actions, but only assert the final part when we have to view the customer information.

Now when we finally do an assert, we also want to record the result.  We created a custom Listener to capture the result.  The problem we're having now is how to send the result back to our action recorder.

I originally ran a PHPUnit test like so:

```
class SandboxTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { /* tests */ }
$stepTracker = new QA_StepTracker(); // Our custom action recorder
$suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite();
$listener = new QA_Listener(); // Our customer listener
$listener->setStepTracker($stepTracker); // Passing the action recorder object to our customer listener
$result = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult();    
$suite->addTestSuite('SandboxTest');
$result->addListener($listener);
$suite->run($result);
```

This works as I expect it to, though it feels like running it this way I'm losing out a lot of functionality the `phpunit` command has to offer.  I want to go back to using the `phpunit` command and use a `phpunit.xml` config file to define the custom listener.

Checking the PHPUnit documentation, I noticed you can pass parameters when you define a customer listener in `phpunit.xml`.

```
<listeners>
  <listener class="MyListener" file="/optional/path/to/MyListener.php">
    <arguments>
      <array>
        <element key="0">
          <string>Sebastian</string>
        </element>
      </array>
      <integer>22</integer>
      <string>April</string>
      <double>19.78</double>
      <null/>
      <object class="stdClass"/>
    </arguments>
  </listener>
</listeners>
```

is equivalent to

```
$listener = new MyListener(
  array('Sebastian'),
  22,
  'April',
  19.78,
  NULL,
  new stdClass
);
```

According to the example, it looks like I could pass in an object... but it would be a newly instantiated object and not a pre-existing one.

Also, if we were to use the example above, we would get rid of `setStepTracker()` in our customer listener and pass in the action recorder object through the customer listener's `__construct()`

## Question

Is it at all possible to pass in a variable through a custom listener via `phpunit.xml`?

We would also define a bootstrap to initialize the action recorder.

If not, would the best course of action make the action recorder object global in the bootstrap and have the custom listener access it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `phpunit.xml` is processed before `bootstrap.php` but the listener is created afterwards, you can use global variables in your listener's constructor.

```
// bootstrap.php
$stepTracker = new QA_StepTracker();

// listener
class QA_Listener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{
    public function __construct() {
        global $stepTracker;
        $this->stepTracker = $stepTracker;
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update:** Fixed to take into account that `bootstrap.php` is executed before creating the listener.

Comment: I've only been doing OOP for about a year (mainly in PHP), and I haven't written any singleton-type classes.  If stepStepTracker() was static, would it be the same as calling it directly like QA_Listener::setStepTracker($stepTracker) and get the same result?

Is the custom listener in `phpunit.xml` really processed (instantiated or hooked in, whatever it needs to be done) before `bootstrap.php`?  My bootstrap has `$QA_STEP_TRACKER = new QA_StepTracker()` and QA_Listener's construct has `global $QA_STEP_TRACKER` and is able to process it as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: I just did a quick test, and it appears that while `phpunit.xml` is *processed* first, the listener is created *after* executing `bootstrap.php`. Thus, the listener's constructor can indeed depend on global variables created in `bootstrap.php`.